# Laravel symlink Permission denied on ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

Using this command in controller `Artisan::call("storage:link");`
No issue on shared hosting.

On AWS EC2 returning this error message "symlink(): Permission denied
".
on EC2 Terminal using this command `php artisan  storage:link` same issue ..

But `sudo php artisan  storage:link` works fine..
I want to use this command `Artisan::call("storage:link")` without going to Terminal but how can ?

Comment: the `Artisan::call("storage:link")` is performed by the webserver user that runs your laravel app. If you are using nginx you have to give `wwwdata` permissions to write and if you use apache you have to give `apache` permissions

Comment: already user in wwwdata group.using this command "sudo chown -R USER:www-data /var/www/html/"

Comment: Try these commands `sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache && sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving my answer here in case someone needed the solution for Mac users

On macOS, you can use

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /path/to/app/folder
```